# Solana Token Creation

Tags: rust, blockchain, solana, solana-cli

I am trying to create a token in Solana using the command:

```
 spl-token create-token --url devnet
```

But all I am getting is the following error.

> error: unrecognized signer source

I am also using a Windows 10 Professional instead of MacBook.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Solana CLI on Windows.
I recommend using WSL if you're on Windows.
You can refer to this doc -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

And inside WSL, run the following commands one by one.

```sh
apt upgrade
apt update
apt install nodejs
apt install npm
apt install python3-pip
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.5.7/install)"
source $HOME/.cargo/env
export PATH="/root/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH"
export RUST_LOG=solana_runtime::system_instruction_processor=trace,solana_runtime::message_processor=debug,solana_bpf_loader=debug,solana_rbpf=debug
solana-test-validator --log
```

Now you should be able to create a token on your localnet.

Comment: This works now. I installed wsl2 and ubuntu on windows. Thanks a lot!